# Measuring Time in Linux Kernel Space With Sub-Microsecond Precision

Tags: c, linux, time, linux-kernel

I am currently using the `do_gettimeofday()` function to measure time in the kernel, which gives me microsecond precision. Is there anything available that is more precise than this (maybe on the order of nanoseconds)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure so "precisely"...? And your hardware is not as deterministic as you think (cache misses may change the timing a lot)

Comment: I want to measure the time it takes a certain piece of hardware to perform a certain operation. I am measuring this in its driver.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ktime_get()` function returns `ktime_t`, which has nanosecond resolution.

Comment: The following code using this functions seems to produce 0: long long int nsTime =  ktime_to_ns(ktime_get());
 printk("start time in ns is %d", nsTime); Any idea why?

Comment: @JohnRoberts: You need to use `%lld` to print out a `long long int`.

Comment: @caf: I've a similar problem, i.e., I'm getting 0 ns.
code looks something like this...
start = ktime_get();
      ...
      function();
      ...
      end = ktime_get();
      actual_time = ktime_to_ns(ktime_sub(end,start));
      printk(KERN_INFO "Time taken = %lld\n", (long long)actual_time);

Comment: @caf Is there a way i can map ktime_get() to something of same unit in userspace? If yes, please answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224325/ktime-get-equivalent-from-user-space

Answer (score 5):

As I know, the most precise timer should be the processor specific counter register (such as [TSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) in x86). Linux kernel provide rdtsc, rdtscl, rdtscll macros from the "./arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h" file to read this register value. For ARM, [cycle counter register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0290g/Bihcgfcf.html).

These registers are all different from CPU to CPU. Common interface to access it is "get_cycles" function which is declared in <linux/timex.h> file.

Maybe, [this document](https://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-1.shtml) can be helpful.

Comment: Isn't TSC too unreliable when it comes to multi-core machines?

Comment: You're right. In multi-core machine, should be careful to use TSC register from a specific CPU.

Comment: "This document" = broken link