# ktime_get() equivalent in user space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, uptime

I want to map the time taken through `ktime_get()` at kernel space to something of the same unit from user space.

Is there any proc entry or any other source(at user level) which can be compared with ktime_get()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)`(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`.